# Udp Listeners in c# (unity)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I use following code to get all udp listeners in unity

```
var ips = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpListeners();
foreach(IPEndPoint ip in ips)
   {
        print(ip.ToString());
   }
```

and if I open a udp port with netcat using following command

```
nc -L -p 2 -u
```

the code prints that there is a listenter on port **512** instead of **2**

Why?

EDIT: code works fine when i run it in a Visual Studio command line program but not in the game

Comment: What Unity have to do with this?

Comment: @arrowd i wrote my code for a game in  unity

Comment: What platform is this not working on? What happens when you build it instead of trying it from the Editor? Also what's your Unity version?

Comment: @Programmer windows 10, it gives me same results when i build it, 5.6.0

Comment: Probably because you are using Unity with old mono. Download Unity 2017 and this problem may be gone. I use 2017 and the problem does not exist here.

Comment: @Programmer ok I will try it, thanks